# How to sum DataGridView cell value with ComboBox criteria?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a `form1` and `combobox1` and `textbox2` in `form2`. I am matching value of `combobox1` value with `form1` DataGridView and doing sum of DataGridView specific cells with `combobox1` selected value. my ComboBox has values 1,2,3,4 and I want sum DataGridView specific cells when ComboBox selected value match with DataGridView value but my code sum all cells. how to do this please suggest me?

```
Private Sub cn()

    Dim totalcn As Double
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView2.Rows
        If rw.Cells(2).Value = ComboBox1.Text Then

            'if you have the other column to get the result you  could add a new one like these above 
            For index As Integer = 0 To Form1.DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
                totalcn += Convert.ToInt32(Form1.DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
            Next
        End If           
    Next
    Label11.Text = totalcn.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an extra loop. Also I can't figure out if we are working with `Integer` or `Double` values. I used Double in the code but you can easily change it to Integer. Instead of `Convert.To` use the simple optimized vb specific `CInt` if you are sure that the values are all Integers. Safer is the `.TryParse`.

```
Private Sub cn()
    Dim totalcn As Double
    Dim cellDoub As Double
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView2.Rows
        If rw.Cells(2).Value.ToString = ComboBox1.Text Then
            If Double.TryParse(rw.Cells(1).Value.ToString, cellDoub) Then
                totalcn += cellDoub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Label11.Text = totalcn.ToString
End Sub
```